# Is it possible to merge multiple FFMPEG commands (cuts, slow down, watermark) into one in order to increase performance?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I wrote a small piece of software in PHP, using FFMPEG commands via shell exec. The final purpose is to take a 7 seconds MP4 file from a GoPro and transform it in order to achieve a sort of boomerang effect:

- crop the video to 1080 width/height

```
ffmpeg -i ./files/video_small/$latestVideo -filter:v \"crop=1080:1080:420:0\" ./files/video_small/outcrop_$cod.mp4 2>&1");
```

- first second should run normally

```
ffmpeg.exe -t 1 -i ./files/video_small/outcrop_$cod.mp4 ./files/video_small/out1_$cod.mp4 2>&1");
```

- the next two seconds will run at slow motion with a 2x factor

```
ffmpeg.exe -ss 00:00:01 -t 2 -i ./files/video_small/outcrop_$cod.mp4 -filter_complex \"[0:v]setpts=2*PTS[v]\" -map \"[v]\" ./files/video_small/out2_$cod.mp4 2>&1");
```

- the next second will speed up at 4x factor

```
ffmpeg.exe -ss 00:00:03 -t 1 -i ./files/video_small/outcrop_$cod.mp4 -filter_complex \"[0:v]setpts=0.25*PTS[v]\" -map \"[v]\" ./files/video_small/out3_$cod.mp4 2>&1");
```

- the next 2 seconds again slow motion

```
ffmpeg.exe -ss 00:00:04 -t 2 -i ./files/video_small/outcrop_$cod.mp4 -filter_complex \"[0:v]setpts=2*PTS[v]\" -map \"[v]\" ./files/video_small/out4_$cod.mp4 2>&1");
```

- final second again normal speed

```
ffmpeg.exe -ss 00:00:06 -i ./files/video_small/outcrop_$cod.mp4 ./files/video_small/out5_$cod.mp4 2>&1");
```

- concatenate the above parts to achieve the modified clip

```
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -i ./files/video_small/files_$cod.txt -c copy  ./files/video_small/output1_$cod.mp4 2>&1");
```

- then append the resulting clip in reverse

```
ffmpeg -i ./files/video_small/output1_$cod.mp4 -filter_complex \"[0:v]reverse,fifo[r];[0:v][r] concat=n=2:v=1 [v]\" -map \"[v]\" ./files/video_small/output2_$cod.mp4 2>&1");
```

- add watermark

```
ffmpeg -i ./files/video_small/output2_$cod.mp4 -i ./files/watermark-video1080.png -filter_complex \"[0:v][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:10[outv]\" -map [outv] -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast ./files/video_small/output3_$cod.mp4 2>&1");
```

- add audio (we can discard the original audio in any of the above steps)

```
ffmpeg -i ./files/video_small/output3_$cod.mp4 -i ./files/video_small/sound-hip-hop.mp3 -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest ./files/video_small/output_final_$latestVideo 2>&1");
```

Right now it runs ok, but I have a problem with performance, the whole process lasts about 50 seconds on my 8th gen i7.

I am very new to the capabilities of ffmpeg and I was wondering if any of the below commands can be optimized or if any of the steps can be merged into one, as I can see the syntax is quite powerful.

Thanks!

I was expecting this to run a little bit faster, ideally half the time it takes right now.
As far as I have observed, the longest part is appending the resulting clip in reverse, perhaps I am adding something too heavy and unnecessary in the reverse filter.

Comment: Yes, by combining individual filters into a filtergraph, you remove extra muxing and demuxing. I suggest reading the [filtering manual](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) and try to do as many as you can in one filtergraph.

Comment: @kesh, thanks for the suggestion, ultimately I will dig down into the documentation. I know it's not appreciated to ask questions without some effort to read the docs, I admit I was looking for a shortcut, but I am totally new to the whole video editing concept. I don't know what muxing and demuxing means.